# switch to a frame with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, iframe, nightwatch.js

the UI I am testing is using an iframe. I am trying to switch to that iframe with the ".frame(0)" call.

```
module.exports = {
    "test" : function (browser) {
    browser
        .url("my_url")
        .waitForElementVisible(".frame-application-scroll-wrapper", 30000)
        .frame(0)
        .waitForElementPresent("#page-content", 30000)
        .end();
    }
};
```

However, #page-content is never seen which makes me think that the change frame command did not work (but returns no error neither).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: It may be that the Iframe isn't loaded before the method is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as Neoaptt mentioned (Thanks!) the issue was that the iframe element was either not present or not loaded. Adding a pause solved my issue.

By the way, if you want to exit the selected frame you should use ".frame(null)"

```
module.exports = {
    "test" : function (browser) {
    browser
        .url("my_url")
        .waitForElementVisible(".frame-application-scroll-wrapper", 30000)
        // give time to the iframe to be available
        .pause(5000)
        .frame(0)
                .waitForElementPresent("#page-content", 30000)
                .frame(null)
         // we are now back to the main page
         // ... more code here ...
         .end();
    }
};
```

What also helped me to debug was to use the --verbose option, for example:

```
nightwatch -t tests/test4.js --verbose
```

This will display in your terminal all the data exchanged between nodejs and selenium.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: If the element is visible, doesn't that imply that the iframe exists and is available?

Comment: Hi Paul. I was wondering if you knew how to click on an element in an iframe. I have managed to do it but then it's erroring because the click closes the iframe but that is expected behaviour

Comment: @RedBaron, in that case, you might want to execute that click from the parent with an `execute` script (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp). In that way, even if the iframe disappears, your script will continue running. It's just an assumption. Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of nightwatch is `.frameParent()` instead of `.frame(null)` to get back to the parent document, just in case any one else finds this post :)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/frame.html), `.frame(null)` takes the browser back to the default frame. Useful if you have nested frames since you don't need to loop over them to return to the top frame.