# Accessing an iframe with nightwatch without a fixed id

Tags: iframe, frame, nightwatch.js

I have

```
<div class="ap-content" id="office-addon">
  <div class="ap-iframe-container iframe-init" id="office-addon__5e83ed1">
    <iframe id="office-addon__5e83ed1">
      <!-- As it appears in the dev console: -->
      #document
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div id="addon"></div>
          </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
  <div>
<div>
```

I want to access it with nightwatch like so:

```
browser
  .waitForElementPresent('#office-addon', 20000);
  .frame('#office-addon iframe')
  .waitForElementPresent('#addon', 1000)
  .end();
```

But it times out waiting for #addon, though #addon is in the browser. How do I have to write the frame() parameters? The iframe id changes with every page build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was like following:

```
browser.getAttribute('#office-addon iframe', 'id', id => {
  browser
    .frame(id.value)

    ...
});
```

It didn't work directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select it by id, you probably ought to try a starts with selector like:

```
.frame("iframe[id^='office-addon']")
```

If it's always the nth iframe you can index in

```
// select the first iframe
.frame(0)
// go back to the original html content
.frame()
```

Comment: The iframe has not an id 'office-addon'.

Comment: The HTML you provided shows that it does, so update your HTML example. I just gave you the "starts with' selector. Whatever your iframe is <iframe id="foo-bar__5e83ed1"> .frame("iframe[id^='foo-bar']") should work.

Answer (score -1):

Iframes are elements to display another page, and it will not render any html written inside of it unless your browser doesn't support iframes. So that div with the id #addon is never being rendered in the first place.

Comment: Sure. But I meant the actual webpage that is displayed in the iframe. Now I wrote it a little more verbose.

Comment: Oh sorry it's hard to tell who knows basic html around here. Then maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548030/switch-to-a-frame-with-nightwatch-js#27549340 . It might be that your iframe isnt loaded yet. So adding a pause might help.